# how to check if pixel value is increased from 255 in matlab while increasing the brightness of the image?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

i am writing the code of matlab in which i just read the image and then i add + 50 on each pixel of the image it works fine and along with it i want to check the pixel value with if statment if pixel value exceed to 255 then this pixel value set to 255. but the if statment not working
here is my code

```
m1 = imread('owl.pgm');
m2  = imread('mecca06.pgm');
for i=1: size(m1,1)
    for j=1: size(m1,2)
        m1(i,j) = m1(i,j)+270;
       if m1(i,j)>=255
            m1(i,j)= 255;
       
            
        end

    end
end
figure
imshow(m1)
```

Comment: convert `m1` to double, then run your code, then convert to `uint8` again.

Answer (score 3):

In MATLAB, integer addition is saturated. That means that, if `m1` is `uint8` (as it usually is returned from `imread`), then `m1+50` will never be more than 255, if the sum would surpass that value, it would be set to 255 instead.

So, MATLAB automatically does what you wanted to accomplish, you don't need anything special for that.

The code in your post can be replaced by:

```matlab
m1 = imread('owl.pgm');
m2 = imread('mecca06.pgm');

m1 = m1 + 270;

figure
imshow(m1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to loop over all pixels, you can use the image as a matrix and simply do something like:

```
m1 = imread('owl.pgm');
m1 = min(255,m1+50);
```

Edit:
Depending on what datatype `im1` has you may need to convert it first to something that can handle the operation you want to do, e.g. an 8-Bit integer allows only numbers upto 255. In that case you may have to convert to a 16-Bit Integer or just a floating point number. You can convert back afterwards:

```
m1 = imread('owl.pgm');
m1 = double(m1);
m1 = min(255,m1+50);
m1 = uint8(m1);
```